# fuse 7.0 JPA persistence.xml schema is waiting for namespace handlers

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I've tried all namespace handlers which are in JPA 2.1 registry persistence_1_0.xsd,persistence_2_0.xsd,persistence_2_1.xsd. As a result, none of them worked and thrown below error.

2.0,2.1
is waiting for namespace handlers [http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence]
1.0 
is waiting for namespace handlers [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence]

Let me know the cause of the issue.

Many Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Any more details? How are you deploying the persistence bundle (the one with `META-INF/persistence.xml`)? What JPA features did you install? How are you building the persistence bundle? Any particular error message / stack trace?

Comment: when placed persistence.xml file under META-INF directory fuse 7.0 thrown following error javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named camel.  So I moved persistence.xml file under OSGI-INF/blueprint then it was able to load the file. but it thrown below error.

Comment: 2019-10-23 15:25:37,554 | INFO  | XNIO-4 task-14       | o.a.a.b.c.BlueprintExtender      | 47 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.9.0 | Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle DEMO-PREP/4.1.0
2019-10-23 15:25:41,899 | INFO  | XNIO-4 task-22       | o.a.a.b.c.BlueprintContainerImpl | 47 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.9.0 | Bundle DEMO-PREP/4.1.0 is waiting for namespace handlers [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence]

Comment: I've installed jpa/2.6.1 existing fuse7.0 feature

Answer (score 1):

If you check:

```
karaf@root()> feature:info jpa
Feature jpa 2.7.2
Description:
  OSGi Persistence Container
Details:
  JPA implementation provided by Apache Aries JPA 2.x. NB: this feature doesn't provide the JPA engine, you have to install one by yourself (OpenJPA for instance)
Feature has no configuration
Feature has no configuration files
Feature has no dependencies.
Feature contains followed bundles:
  mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence/javax.persistence_2.1/2.7.2
  mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1.redhat-2 (overriden from mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1)
  mvn:org.osgi/org.osgi.service.jdbc/1.0.0
  mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.coordinator/1.0.2 start-level=30
  mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.api/2.7.2 start-level=30
  mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container/2.7.2 start-level=30
  mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.support/2.7.2 start-level=30
Feature contains followed conditionals:
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no configuration
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no configuration files
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no dependencies.
Conditional(aries-blueprint) contains followed bundles:
  mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.blueprint/2.7.2 start-level=30
```

You'll see *NB: this feature doesn't provide the JPA engine, you have to install one by yourself (OpenJPA for instance)*. This description seems old. You need actual JPA provider, like:

```
karaf@root()> feature:info hibernate
Feature hibernate 5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001
Description:
  Hibernate JPA engine support
Feature has no configuration
Feature has no configuration files
Feature depends on:
  wrap 0.0.0
  hibernate-orm 5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001
Feature contains followed bundles:
  mvn:net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.5.redhat-00001 (overriden from mvn:net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.5.redhat-00001)
Feature has no conditionals.
```

(versions of bundles from Fuse newer than 7.0).

So please install additionally `hibernate` feature:

```
karaf@root()> feature:install hibernate

karaf@root()> la -l|grep hibernate
249 │ Active   │  80 │ 5.0.4.Final-redhat-00001  │ mvn:org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final-redhat-00001
250 │ Active   │  80 │ 5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001 │ mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001
251 │ Active   │  80 │ 5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001 │ mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/5.3.10.Final-redhat-00001
```

EDIT 2019-11-07:

I checked (upcoming Fuse 7.5, but should be valid for 7.0) and found the problem you have.

If you check:

```
karaf@root()> ls PersistenceProvider
[javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider]
-------------------------------------------
 javax.persistence.provider = org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
 service.bundleid = 250
 service.id = 468
 service.scope = bundle
Provided by : 
 hibernate-osgi (250)
Used by: 
 Apache Aries JPA Specification 2.1 API (244)
 Camel Content-Based Router Example [EXAM-PREP] (256)
```

you'll see there's `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` JPA provider registered by Hibernate.

You've however added (in `META-INF/persistence.xml`):

```xml
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

You should either remove this provider or use `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` because it affects an OSGi filter created by `org.apache.aries.jpa.container.impl.PersistenceProviderTracker#createFilter` for your bundle. So that's the reason why you didn't have EMF registered.

With this change, I found it works:

```
karaf@root()> ls EntityManagerFactory
[javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]
----------------------------------------
 hibernate.connection.pool_size = 25
 hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
 hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
 hibernate.show_sql = true
 javax.persistence.jdbc.driver = org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
 javax.persistence.jdbc.url = jdbc:derby:memory:order;create=true
 javax.persistence.jdbc.user = sa
 osgi.unit.name = camel
 osgi.unit.provider = org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
 osgi.unit.version = 4.1.4
 service.bundleid = 256
 service.id = 501
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by : 
 Camel Content-Based Router Example [EXAM-PREP] (256)
Used by: 
 Camel Content-Based Router Example [EXAM-PREP] (256)
```

Comment: this is to inform you that I had installed hibernate, hibernate orm, openjpa all features but it is looking for schema definitions. I've gone through the all the packages which are present in above features  and confirms that mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence/javax.persistence_2.1/2.7.2 has above schema xsd files also it is an active state. but it throws waiting for namespace handlers.

Comment: _So I moved persistence.xml file under OSGI-INF/blueprint_ - this may be a problem. it has to be in `META-INF`.

Comment: when I placed persistence.xml file under META-INF/persistence.xml directory. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named camel. org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence provider used in persistence xml and the package exported on hibernate-entitymanager bundle. could you please Let me know the cause of the issue.

Comment: I was able to run the bundle by camel:run plugin but fuse 7.0 not .

Comment: fuse 7.0 is not even loading META-INF/persistence.xml. I've installed the bundle without META-INF/persistence.xml, As a result it thrown same error. javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named camel.

Comment: META-INF/persistence.xml should be processed by aries-jpa (in particular - by org.apache.aries.jpa.container bundle). But ONLY if your bundle has `Meta-Persistence` header in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Did you check the quickstarts accompanying Fuse?

Comment: Kindly see my MANIFEST FILE which has Meta-Persistence details. Manifest-Version: 1.0
...
Bundle-Blueprint: OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
Bundle-Version: 4.1.4
....
DynamicImport-Package: *, org.hibernate.proxy, javassist.util.proxy
Meta-Persistence: META-INF/persistence.xml
....
Require-Capability: osgi.service;effective:=active;objectClass="javax.
 persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider";javax.persistence.provider="org.
 hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence",osgi.service;;osgi.jdbc.driver.
 class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver",osgi.extender;osgi.exten
 der="aries.jpa"

Comment: _I was able to run the bundle by camel:run plugin but fuse 7.0 not_ - which is strange, because `camel:run` uses Felix Connect... Can you please share your project via github?

Comment: I've moved files to github repository. https://github.com/johngabriel7/Demojpa

Comment: Can anyone share simple jpa demo project for fuse 7

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have much time checking your example. Here's [official `camel-xa` example with PostgreSQL, XA, Camel and Hibernate](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/tree/7.x.redhat-7-x/persistence/camel-xa). Here's [the readme](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/karaf-quickstarts/blob/7.x.redhat-7-x/persistence/readme.adoc#camel-xa-example).

Comment: Thank you, I had deployed camel-xa in Fuse 7.0 but it thrown following error. "org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.9.0 | Bundle DEMO-PREP/4.1.5 is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)]" . According to fuse documentation, above osgi service by default exported by JPA features. But which is not exported  and it thrown error. Should we export manually above osgi service. reference code : "<reference id="entityManagerFactory" interface="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />"

Comment: Did you deploy data source needed by EMF?

Comment: yes, I deployed datasource sucessfully, Kindly check the logs.Found DataSource for camel osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresDS)
Found DataSource for camel osgi:service/javax.sql.DataSource/(osgi.jndi.service.name=jdbc/postgresDS)
Persistence units added for bundle DEMO-PREP event 128
Registering EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit camel
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: camel]

Comment: [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService, id=299, bundle=233/mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/org.apache.aries.jpa.container/2.6.1]: Unexpected problem updating configuration org.apache.aries.jpa.camel
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversService]
 Bundle DEMO-PREP/4.2.0 is waiting for dependencies [(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)]
Unable to start blueprint container for bundle DEMO-PREP/4.2.0 due to unresolved dependencies [(objectClass=javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)]

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz Grzybek, The issue was due to some additional features which I installed and after I removed those features it is working fine. Thank you for the help.